# How do i display unique php data using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have this little project i'm working on which stores data in a database using php then loads all saved data as lists into a div asynchronously. it works fine but i am currently facing a php-javascript crisis ...Here is a summary of what happens

**Expected result:**

- when a list is clicked, display the unique clicked title

**Actual result:**

- Always displays the title that was last saved even when a different one is clicked.

#### Please guys i need help to achieve the 'expected' result.

here is a snippet of the php code

```
//users name
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];

//establishing connection to notes database
$dbconn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','notesdb');
if(!$dbconn){
    die("Connection failed:". mysqli_connect_error($dbconn));
}

//order by desc i.e Most recent appears always at the top
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT * FROM notes_log ORDER BY id DESC");
/*
loops through the query result and presents it in  an array i.e 
'username:title:body:date' and is displayed in the notes-log div.
*/
while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
if($extract['username'] === $uname){
    $title = $extract['note-title']; 
echo "<div class='saved-note' >";
echo "<a href='#'><span id='note-title' class='note-title' onclick='displayNote()'>". truncate($title) ."</span></a>";
echo "<div class='trig-dropdown'><span class='fa fa-ellipsis-v' id='fa-ellipsis-v'></span><div class='dropdowncontent-noteslog' id='dropdowncontent-noteslog'><a href='#'>delete</a></div></div>";
echo " <span id='note-date'> " .$extract['date-saved']."</span>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

}

JS

```
function displayNote(){
var res = document.getElementById("note-title");
alert(res.innerHTML);     
}
```

Comment: well `id` has to be unique, so add something to it to make it unique, otherwise you're getting the first item that has id `note-title`

Comment: @WilomGfx its a loop (unknown number of rows), how can i possibly create a unique id for every resulting row?

Comment: well use the notes `id` ? or the title if its unique. Be creative :P

Comment: Or by simply increasing a counter variable inside the loop, and appending that value to a static prefix …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Try passing `this` in your onclick function,

```
<span id='note-title' class='note-title' onclick='displayNote(this)'>
```

and get your parameter on javascript also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayNote(this){
  alert(this.innerHTML)
}</script>
```

That should work.

**Note:** It would be better if you make your id unique every loop.

---

**Method 2:**

Make your id unique for each loop.

`echo "<span id='note-title-".$i."' class='note-title' onclick='displayNote()'>"`

Your ids would be `note-title-0` , `note-title-1`, ... and so on.

Comment: Method 1 worked like a charm. But considering Method 2, how then do i reference the id in JS as it contains a php variable?  thanks for help though

Comment: Instead of using a php variable, you can use a javascript variable. You just have to concatinate "note-title-" with the javascript variable you are using.